# Display custom field on Woocommerce category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom field for Woocommerce product categories based on a question here with this:

```
//Product Cat Edit page
function wh_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {

//getting term ID
$term_id = $term->term_id;

// retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field.
$wh_meta_title = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_title', true);
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="wh_meta_title"><?php _e('Meta Title', 'wh');  ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="wh_meta_title" id="wh_meta_title" value="<?php echo  esc_attr($wh_meta_title) ? esc_attr($wh_meta_title) : ''; ?>">
        <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter a meta title, <= 60 character', 'wh'); ?></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}

add_action('product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'wh_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 1);

// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function wh_save_taxonomy_custom_meta($term_id) {

$wh_meta_title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'wh_meta_title');
update_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_title', $wh_meta_title);
}

add_action('edited_product_cat', 'wh_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 1);
```

And to display it I have this:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_my_page_schemas');
function insert_my_page_schemas() {
if ( ! is_product_category() ) { 
return;
}
$wh_meta_title = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_title', true);
if ( ! $wh_meta_title ) {
return;
}
echo '<script type="application/ld+json">'. $wh_meta_title .'</script>';
}
```

But it is not being added to the footer. What do I need to change?

I tried my functions above and nothing is displayed in the footer, the field is created though.

Comment: Where do you expect `$term_id` to come from inside that `insert_my_page_schemas` function ...?

Comment: @CBroe I am new to PHP. Could you help me with this?

Comment: This hook does not pass any parameters to the callback function, and the term ID is not available as a global variable either, AFAIK. Try and use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$term_id` is not defined in `insert_my_page_schemas()`

You need to find it.

```
$term_id = get_queried_object_id();
$wh_meta_title = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_title', true);
```

This will work only on a category page, not a post/product within a category.